# How to disable subquery flattening in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, subquery

If I define `SQLITE_OMIT_SUBQUERY` I cannot run a subquery clause. How can I revise the source code to disable the optimization and run as:

> When a subquery occurs in the FROM clause of a SELECT, the simplest behavior is to evaluate the subquery into a transient table, then run the outer SELECT against the transient table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just break one of the rules listed in [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening).

The easiest would be to add an `OFFSET` clause that has no effect:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT ...
      FROM ...
      LIMIT -1 OFFSET 0)
WHERE ...
```

---

If you really want to change the source code: just return from the `flattenSubquery` function in `select.c` without doing anything.
It already has the following line at the beginning:

```
if( OptimizationDisabled(db, SQLITE_QueryFlattener) ) return 0;
```